# Can setInterval() be put in the last .then() method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, fetch-api

A new javascript question, again, and again...

(Updated)

`a` is a string where I input a word, it will then be sent to a Dictionary API and do the `fetchApi()`. After getting the result, if `a` matches the `result[0].word`, it will trigger the function `Func1()`, if not then it will trigger the other function `Func2()`.

What I'd like to ask is there any way to use `setInterval()` for the function `data(result)`, after deleting the part `.then(result => data(result))` in the function `fetchApi(a)`? Or can I only put `setInterval()` for both functions `Func1()` and `Func2()`?

Thank you very much!

```
var a = "";

function fetchApi(a) {
  let url = `${url}${a}`;
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(result => data(result));
  }

function data(result) {
  // console.log(result);
  if (a == result) {
    Func1();
  } else {
    Func2();
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: There's not quite enough information to understand what you want. Do you want something like `.then(result => myInterval = setInterval(x => { data(x) }, 1000, result));`. Otherwise, you might want to consider just putting fetchApi in an interval and running the whole thing on a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `setInterval()` on `data()` will not do anything because `result` will never change once it has returned. You need to call the whole `fetchApi` function again if you're expecting the `result` to be updated later on.